# Neo4j Divide ( / ) by Zero ( 0 )

Tags: neo4j, cypher, division, divide-by-zero

In neo4j I am querying

```
MATCH (n)-[t:x{x:"1a"}]->()
WHERE n.a > 1 OR n.b > 1 AND toFloat(n.a) / (n.a+n.b) * 100 < 90
RETURN DISTINCT n, toFloat(n.a) / (n.a + n.b) * 100
ORDER BY toFloat(n.a) / (n.a + n.b) * 100 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

but I got  `/ by zero`  error.

Since I declared one of n.a or n.b should be 1, if both zero it should skip that row and I shouldn't get this error. This looks like a logic issue in Neo4j. There is no problem when I delete `AND toFloat(n.a)/(n.a+n.b)*100 < 90` from WHERE clause. But I want the results only lower than 90. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Wrap `n.a>1 OR n.b>1` in parentheses.

Comment: @NicoleWhite It doesn't work, same result again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the second condition, `toFloat(na) / (na + nb) * 100 < 90`, is tested before the first. Look at the `Filter(1)` operator in this execution plan:

```
+--------------+---------------+------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     Operator | EstimatedRows | Rows | DbHits |                                            Identifiers |                                                                                                                                                                                      Other |
+--------------+---------------+------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Projection |             1 |    3 |      0 | anon[111], anon[138], n, toFloat(n.a)/(n.a + n.b)* 100 |                                                                                                                                                                       anon[111]; anon[138] |
|          Top |             1 |    3 |      0 |                                   anon[111], anon[138] |                                                                                                                                                                             {  AUTOINT6};  |
|     Distinct |             0 |    3 |     24 |                                   anon[111], anon[138] |                                                                                                                                                                       anon[111], anon[138] |
|    Filter(0) |             0 |    3 |      6 |                                         anon[29], n, t |                                                                                                                                                                     t.x == {  AUTOSTRING0} |
|  Expand(All) |             1 |    3 |      6 |                                         anon[29], n, t |                                                                                                                                                                          (  n@7)-[t:x]->() |
|    Filter(1) |             1 |    3 |     34 |                                                      n | (Ors(List(n@7.a > {  AUTOINT1}, Multiply(Divide(ToFloatFunction(  n@7.a),Add(  n@7.a,  n@7.b)),{  AUTOINT3}) < {  AUTOINT4})) AND Ors(List(  n@7.a > {  AUTOINT1},   n.b > {  AUTOINT2}))) |
| AllNodesScan |             4 |    4 |      5 |                                                      n |                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+--------------+---------------+------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can get around this by force breaking the filter into two clauses.

```
MATCH (n)-[t:x { x:"1a" }]->()
WHERE n.a > 1 OR n.b > 1
WITH n
WHERE toFloat(n.a) / (n.a + n.b) * 100 < 90
RETURN DISTINCT n, toFloat(n.a) / (n.a + n.b) * 100
ORDER BY toFloat(n.a) / (n.a + n.b) * 100 DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

I found this behavior surprising, but as I think about it I suppose it isn't wrong for the execution engine to rearrange the filter in this way. There may be the assumption that the condition will abandon early on failing the first declared condition, but Cypher is exactly that: declarative. So we express the "what", not the "how", and in terms of the "what" `A and B` is equivalent to `B and A`.

Here is the query and a sample graph, you can check if it translates to your actual data:
http://console.neo4j.org/r/f6kxi5

Comment: Yes, it is working! Thank you so much for detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can either of `n.a` or `n.b` be negative? I was able to reproduce this with:

```
WITH -2 AS na, 2 AS nb
WHERE (na > 1 OR nb > 1) AND toFloat(na)/(na+nb)*100 < 90
RETURN na, nb
```

And I get: `/ by zero`

Perhaps try changing your `WHERE` clause to:

```
WITH -2 AS na, 2 AS nb
WHERE (na + nb > 0) AND toFloat(na)/(na+nb)*100 < 90
RETURN na, nb
```

And I get: zero rows.

Comment: No, they cannot be negative.

Comment: Can you post example data so that the error can be reproduced?

Comment: I think it's the `n.a=0, n.b=0` case that breaks ("if both zero it should skip"). If so, here's a sample graph: http://console.neo4j.org/r/f6kxi5. I've answered what I think is happening but I haven't had coffee yet today so I would be interested to hear what you think.

Comment: @NicoleWhite I cannot share it sorry, but you can reproduce it easily I guess if you want to. Thanks :)

Comment: @jjaderberg Strange. I cannot reproduce with n.a=0 and n.b=0.